# How to use jQuery to apply multiple statement based on selector pattern _pairs_?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe the title not the most descriptive, this is because I do not have deep jQuery knowledge. Feel free to edit.

**Context**

I know jQuery is capable to apply operations on multiple nodes, what the selector selects. So although what am I would like to do is obvious to implement with a for loop, I do not want to end with lame code...

**Question**

Here is what I would like to do:

```
$("#render_myid1").html($("#section_myid1").html());
$("#render_myid2").html($("#section_myid2").html());
// and so on for all #render... with all #section...
```

Is it possible with one line?

Comment: are the elements with the section ids children of the render-elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to `.html()` ([docs here](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)) that returns the desired HTML string.

`this` in the passed in function refers to the current (`render`) element.

```
var renderSelector = '...';  // selector for all render nodes

$(renderSelector).html(function (index, oldHtml) {
    return $('#' + this.getAttribute('id').replace(/^render/, 'section')).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `^=` to select any element whose `id` begins with `render_`, and then use [`.html` with a transforming function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) as its argument:

```
$('[id^="render_"]').html(function(idx, val) {
    var renderIdentifier = this.id.substr(7);
    return $("#section_"+renderIdentifier).html();
});
```

This does the following:

1. Selects all elements whose `id` value begins with `render_`
2. For each element so selected, run it and its HTML through a function
3. Using `this` to refer to the element under consideration, extract the part of the elements `id` that follows `render_`
4. Find the HTML content of the element with `section_` prefixed `id` that matches the extracted part of the `render_` id
5. Have the function return that HTML string, causing it to be used by the `.html` setter

This is far less readable than a simple `for` loop, so I **wouldn't recommend it** for this case, but I demonstrate it for you here since it is generally helpful to understand the prefix selector and `.html` used with a function argument.